# How can we import data to azure documentdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-emulator, nosql

Is there a way to import data(collection) to azure document db from locally generated document db collection.
We will generate data locally and want to push it to azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to  migrate data between the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and the Azure Cosmos DB service,from the [Azure Cosmos DB Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#DocumentDBSource) document,
we could know that we could use [Azure DocumentDB Data Migration Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46436) to migrate data between the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and the Azure Cosmos DB service.

> You can use existing tools like Azure DocumentDB Studio to connect to the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. You can also migrate data between the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and the Azure Cosmos DB service using the Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool.

More details about how to use DocumentDB Data Migration Tool, refer to the [How to import data into Azure Cosmos DB with the DocumentDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#DocumentDBSource)